# apache httpd - RewriteCond SERVER_NAME not equal to SERVER_ADDR

Tags: http, mod-rewrite, apache

I need to redirect the user if the `SERVER_ADDR` and `SERVER_NAME` variables don't match.

I have the following rule in my httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !%{SERVER_ADDR}
RewriteRule .* /myRedirectPage.html [PT]
```

When SERVER_NAME and SERVER_ADDR don't match, I correctly get redirected. **However, I also get redirected even when they are matching.**

If I use the following condition it works for both matching and non-matching scenarios: (where 192.168.1.1 is the server IP)

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !192.168.1.1
```

To check if the variables matched, I used PHP's `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` variables.

How should I write the RewriteCond so that it does not redirect the user if `SERVER_NAME` and `SERVER_ADDR` match?

Comment: That's a little bit confusing. `SERVER_ADDR` (IP) and `SERVER_NAME` (Name) are 2 ways to identify the same domain. So they always "match" because those are the variables passed by the server. On the other hand, one is numeric while the other one is a string.  How do you compare them, even with PHP code?

Comment: I have them displayed using `vardump($_SERVER)` but php identifies both values as strings. I'm making a captive portal where all tcp traffic is redirected to the server. For example, if the user tries to visit `http://www.google.com/`, the user will be redirected to my php page, where `SERVER_ADDR=192.168.1.1` and `SERVER_NAME=www.google.com`.

Comment: SERVER_NAME is what you have in HTTP Host header, when you use IP instead the hostname you can have the same value, in other cases this values can't match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use server variables on the right side of a RewriteCond, so you are matching against the literal string `"%{SERVER_ADDR}"`, not the variable and thus, since your match is negated ("!"), the rule always matches.

I think you can do something like this, though I've never worked with this particular format myself:

```apacheconf
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME},%{SERVER_ADDR} ^([^,]*+),\1$
```

The idea is that you're doing two matches - you're matching `%{SERVER_NAME}` against anything (always matches) and capturing the result, then matching `%{SERVER_ADDR}` against a backreference to the first match, which is the match of `%{SERVER_NAME}`.

Again, I haven't used a rule like that myself, just read about it, so it may need some tweaking.

Comment: Be aware that the content of `%{SERVER_NAME}` is different, depending of the value of UseCanonicalName. If you have it 'On', then `{%SERVER_NAME}` is just carrying the ServerName from the VirtualHost. So maybe you want always use `{%HTTP_HOST}` in your case.

Comment: is there a link to documentation for \1 backreferances?